# Gridview becomes out of shape when rebinds

Tags: c#, gridview, autolayout

I have binded gridview to database and it loads on TICKER's event. It works good but problem is that when it rebinds then GIRDVIEW's layout and shape becomes improper and disturbed, kinda messed up.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" BorderColor="#333333"  Width="550px" OnRowDataBound="GridViewSmsComplaints_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging" >
               <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" /> 
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recieving Date" DataField="RecievingDate" />  
                    <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ToMobileNo" DataField="ToMobileNo" />  --%>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FromMobileNo" DataField="FromMobileNo" /> 
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Message" DataField="Message" >   
                     <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsComplaint">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint"  runat="server" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>    
            <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="20000" ID="RefreshSmsComplaints" OnTick="RefreshSmsComplaints_Tick" />
          </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Ticker:

```
 protected void RefreshSmsComplaints_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ReportViewer1.Visible = false;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ckboxIsComplaint");

            if (checkbox.Checked == true)
            {
                CheckedRows.Add(row.RowIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                CheckedRows.Remove(row.RowIndex);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
            DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
            DataTable dt = ManageRecievedMessage.GetSmsComplaintsByDate(fromDate, toDate);
            //GridViewSmsComplaints.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:keep-all;word-wrap:normal");

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
                //gridViewComplaintsBySubject.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
                GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
                int totalcolums = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = totalcolums;
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found for this date combination";
                GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
                //gridViewComplaintsBySubject.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "SomethingWrong";
            HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
        }
    }
```

Comment: A screenshot would be nice.

Comment: picture isn't gonna posted, error